# Can I change devexpress date edit settings through javascript?

Tags: javascript, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

In my project I have a DateEdit that shows a calendar with:

```
pickerGroup.Items.Add(item => Model.Start, itemSettings =>
{
    itemSettings.NestedExtensionType = FormLayoutNestedExtensionItemType.DateEdit;
    var dateEditSettings = (DateEditSettings)itemSettings.NestedExtensionSettings;

    dateEditSettings.Properties.CalendarProperties.Columns = 2;
    dateEditSettings.Properties.CalendarProperties.Rows = 1;
});
```

My goal is to change these 2 properties if window width is < XX

I was thinking in a javascript function as:

```
function Responsive() {
    var width = screen.width;
    if (width < 1000) {
        settings.Properties.CalendarProperties.Columns = 1;
        settings.Properties.CalendarProperties.Rows = 2;
    } 
    else {

    }
}
```

Is it possible? any help would be greatly apreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could contact with Devexpress developement team and, to answer my own question, No, it's not possible.

their answer:

```
DateEdit does not provide the capability to change the Columns property on the client side. As a workaround I suggest you use @media CSS rules. For example:

@@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .dxeCalendar_DevEx td {
        display: block;
    }
        .dxeCalendar_DevEx td td {
            display: table-cell;
        }
}


Note that it is necessary to set the current theme name instead of the "_DevEx" postfix. Should you have any further questions, feel free to contact us.
```